# web api attribute routing multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a method defined as follows

```
[Route("public/sites/GetAllForWeb")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Domain.Site.Site> GetAllForWeb(DateTime date, int hour, string parameterCode = null)
```

That is then being called as follows (angular)

`return this.http.get<Site[]>("public/sites/GetAllForWeb?date=" + date + "&hour=" + hour + ((parameterCode === undefined) ? "" : "&parameterCode=" + parameterCode)`

Unfortunately the call doesn't match any controller methods, I am assuming because of the lack of parameters in the `Route` attribute.

How should the `Route` attribute be modified to correctly reflect the method signature?

Comment: The route attribute seems correct for this url. Do you have a routePrefix attribute on the controller ? Are the route attributes enabled  ? ( do you have the line config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); in the webapi Config ?)

Comment: Have you tried ([FromURI] DateTime date, int hour) attribute for those two parameters and put /{date}/{hour} in Route attribute?

Comment: @J.Loscos No route prefix, and yes that line is in the config. Are the attributes not required to be in the route attribute for the framework to match the request with the method?

Comment: In your exemple all method arguments are http request parameters since they are after the "?" so you don't need to indicate them in the route attribute.

Comment: That's what I thought...and yet it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have a MVC Controller that is named "public" ? could there be conflicts with other routes ?

Comment: in your test is parameterCode undefined? I think this might not work because the parameterCode argument of the method doesn't have a default value, so the parameter is required in the http request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues is that I didn't add `api` to the `Route` attribute :/

For some reason I was under the impression that `api` in

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

will get prepended to the `Route` attribute

Comment: This is the default route set up for convention routing which finds methods based on controller and action names.  
If you are using the `Route` attribute then you are attempting to use AttributeRouting which should be enabled by calling `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`
If you do that you can delete the default convention route, and you will access your method with the address defined in your route attribute: `public/sites/GetAllForWeb` without the need for the /api bit.